# Как правильно указать параметры для curl?

Tags: xml, api, curl, soap

Делаю такой запрос:

```
curl -u 'user:pass' https://apitest.merlion.com/dl/mlservice3?wsdl \
 -H "Content-Type: text/xml" \
 -H "SOAPAction: https://apitest.merlion.com/dl/mlservice3#getItems" \
 -d @"/home/vg/merlion_sync/req.xml"
```

Содержание req.xml:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mls="https://apitest.merlion.com/dl/mlservice3">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mls:getItems>
         <cat_id>ML250301</cat_id>
         <item_id>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <item></item>
         </item_id>
         <shipment_method>РЕКБ_2_СВ</shipment_method>
         <page>1</page>
         <rows_on_page>10</rows_on_page>
         <last_time_change></last_time_change>
      </mls:getItems>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Ответ приходит стандартный, такой, как без авторизации открыть URL на который делаем запрос. Ответ должен быть - перечень товаров.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Скорее всего там не Basic авторизация